# two way binding not working, when the function is called inside constructor

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

Here is my code:

```
export class ProtocolComponent {
    this.bindelement: Array < any > = [];

    constructor() {
        this.dynamicforms()
    }

    this.dynmaicforms() {
        this.bindelement = [{
            name: 'test1'
        }, {
            name: 'test2'
        }, {
            name: 'test3'}]
        }];
    }
}
```

`bindelement` is called inside my jade, I am getting the error as "name of undefined".

when I call a function inside `oninit` two way binding is not working. Can someone help me out?

Comment: How does the template look like?

Answer (score 2):

This is not entirely proper `TypeScript`. Change your implementation to this, and try again. Also you misspelled the method name `dynamicforms`:

```
export class ProtocolComponent {
    public bindelement: Array<any> = [];

    constructor() {
        this.dynamicforms()
    }

    public dynamicforms() {
        this.bindelement = [{
            name: 'test1'
        }, {
            name: 'test2'
        }, {
            name: 'test3'}]
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, + 1, does `public` accessor needed really?

Comment: It's best practice afaik. It's easier to sort your methods/attributes with `public` first then `protected` and then `private`. Makes your code more readable

Comment: yes I have tried in that way too. But still facing that error. I am using angular2 rc4

Comment: @SharmileMurugaraj have you also changed your method name, `dynamicforms`? You made a typo, dynmaicforms !== dynamicforms

Comment: @SharmileMurugaraj You also say something about `onInit`. Do you get the data dynamically? Can you show an example of your template?

Comment: @SharmileMurugaraj how you are binding ``bindelement` it on view?

Comment: yes i have changed it, while typing I misspelled. Actually this is a example but for my project I am calling using the same scenerio

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar yes

Comment: @PierreDuc  I dont have anything in my jade, just I am having a div `div {{bindelement[0].name}}`

Comment: @PierreDuc and also this is just an example but i am calling a service from where I am getting the dynamic data.

Comment: Change `{{bindelement[0].name}}` to `{{bindelement[0]?.name}}`

Comment: @PierreDuc I couldnot get the values in my jade, when I print the value inside my component I can able to print it? that is my issue

Comment: I am getting the array length as 0 in my jade